# How can I launch a PARENT jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, iframe, parent

I'm trying to figure out how to launch a function from an iframe but the following example won't work, any ideas?

```
<input class='reply' onclick='parent.replytopost()' type='button' value='Reply' />
```

PARENT PAGE FUNCTION (In the body if that makes a difference):

```
<script>
  function replytopost(){
  alert("test");
  parent.document.getElementById('mainbar').innerHTML = "TEST";
  parent.document.getElementById('post_reply').show();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: No errors, nothing happens. I'll post the function in the parent above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me. Look [here](http://phpcode.eu/iframe/)

Why do you call parent.* in non-iframe replytopost script?

Comment: It worked on my server but not on localhost, why would this be?

Comment: the URL is dead. The one you where you said look "here"

Answer (score 1):

This might become an issue with security-tightened browsers (such as Safari).

I ran against the same type of problem recently, and I'm now a happy user of [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage).

You will still have to reference it using `window.parent` but this will prevent the vast majority of issues to happen.

Comment: Use jQuery.postMessage plugin for more browsers support http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

Answer (score 0):

Will `window.opener` work for you? I know it works from a parent to a newWindow. I don't know about iframe.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_opener.asp